# Play Retail Game within Xbox One Developer Mode?

Tags: xbox-one, windows-dev-center

I am trying to find a way to use retail apps inside the developer mode of Xbox One.

Officially, this is not allowed.

Would it be possible to extract the games file from my Xbox and upload it to dev mode?

Answer (score 0):

When in Developer Mode, the security signing on retail games fails. You can't run retail games in Developer Mode by design. That said, it's reasonably quick to switch back and forth. See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/devkit-deactivation#switch-to-retail-mode).